# Using under-development library from another app

Tags: python

I used to have the following structure in my project:

```
foo
 |- foo
 |  \ lib.py
 |- scripts
 |  \ foo.py
 |- web
 |  \ ... # flask app
 \  tests
```

However, for testing/deployment/licensing reasons I refactored web (a flask app) to another repository and so I end up having:

```
foo
 |- foo
 |  \ lib.py
 |- scripts
 |  \ foo.py
 |- web
 |  \ ... # flask app
 \  tests

fooweb
 |- fooweb
 |  \ ... # flask app
 \  tests
```

In the first case, all worked well. Both `foo.py` and the `web` app used `lib.py` and imports were ok since I was under `pip install -e .`.
However, in the new case what's the easiest way to enable flask app to access the foo lib?

After deployment, `fooweb` would depend on `foo` and therefore do a `pip install foo` but during development where both are being simultaneous changed, what's the best practice here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're already using `pip install -e` to install the pacakge during development. Install *both* packages in the same virtualenv, and now they're both importable.

```
python3 -m venv venv
. venv/bin/activate
pip install -e /path/to/first/package
pip install -e /path/to/second/package
```